# xamarin compilation error : no resource found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms(Portable) , after updating Xamarin.Forms to version 2.3.2127 from NuGet I started getting compile time error.
List  of error are as follows

> Error     Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'.
>
> Error     Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'
>
> Error     Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.
>
> Error     Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton'.
>
> Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'colorAccent'.
>
> Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'colorAccent'.
>
> Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'colorPrimary'.
>
> Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'colorPrimaryDark'.
>
> Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'windowActionBar'.
>
> Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'windowActionModeOverlay'.
>
> Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'windowNoTitle'.

Comment: I've seen similar error messages before, if the tooling isn't updated in all of the right places. Did you update your PCL project & Android project to the same version of the Xamarin.Forms package? (It's somewhat common to only update one or the other.)

Comment: Both PLC and android project  have  Xamarin.Forms  version 2.3.2127

Comment: Do you also have the Android SDK packages installed as described in this guide? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/installation/#Android